# Executables published with Visual Studio 2017 stops running

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2017 and .NET C# projects shared on remote host using Samba. Everything works fine from the beginning but some time later all of my softwares stops running. When I double-click on the link on my desktop nothing happening. Usually it have to chech application requirements and etc but it does nothing.

After I delete one of the programs via Start Menu > Uninstall I can successfuly run the second one.

Run application manifest from installation directory doesn't work too. Rebooting PC helps but some time later I'm still stuck with this issue.

I expect software run as usual, but in fact I have to reboot PC or reinstall software.

Comment: Can you please check if anti-virus is blocking your exe. Also check if you can find any log information in event viewer.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the applications are trying to achieve?